# Single linked list, self sorting based on *char input

Tags: c++, list, sorting

I have spent significant amount of time on this and I have finally made it work at all (as in it saves the values and prints them). I want to sort it counter alphabetically. If I add the values into my list they do not print out in the same order I have added them in but it seems kind of random... It seems that the strcpy doesn't work in the way I would imagine it to work...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;


typedef struct list list_t;
struct list{
    list *next;
    char *nam;
    int age;

};

static list_t *top = NULL;


void add_value(char * name1, int age){
    list * neww = (list_t*)malloc(sizeof( list_t));
    //tmp = top;
    neww->age = age;
    neww->nam = (char*)malloc(strlen(name1) + 1);
    neww->next = NULL;
    strcpy(neww->nam, name1);
    list * tmp = (list_t*)malloc(sizeof(list_t));
    tmp = top;
    if (tmp==NULL){
        top = neww;
        //printf("%s\n", top->nam);
    }else
    while (1){


        if (tmp->next == NULL){
            tmp->next = neww;
            break;
        }
        //printf("top - %s %d\n neww - %s %d\n tmp - %s %d", top->nam, top->age, neww->nam, neww->age, tmp->nam, tmp->age);
        if (strcmp(neww->nam, tmp->nam)>=0){
            neww->next = tmp->next;
            tmp->next = neww;
            break;
        }

        tmp = tmp->next;


    }

}


void print(){
    list * tmp = (struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    tmp = top;
    while (tmp){
        printf("%s %d\n", tmp->nam, tmp->age);
        tmp = tmp->next;

    }


}


int main(){

    char namee[100];
    int age;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        scanf("%s %d", &namee, &age);
        add_value(namee, age);
    }

    print();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1: What language? 2: What is the question?

Comment: Maybe you should start by learning how `strcpy` actually works.

Comment: You allocate space for `tmp` in `add_value`, and then immediately overwrite the pointer to that space; I'm pretty sure that's not right.

Comment: I removed the C++ tag since the code is pure C with one exception, the unused include of `<iostream>`. I left that in place because one should be extremely wary of *changing* the substance of a question. Was this wrong?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Outdated idioms notwithstanding, if the code is being pushed through a C++ compiler (and clearly it is), then it is C++ ... making this a C++ question. I have put the tag back.

Comment: "The more you overthink the plumbing, the easier it is to stop up the drain." The logic in add_value() is overengineered, and awkward. The correct implementation only needs a single while() loop, without any if() statements, whatsoever.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet: Thanks. I needed a second opinion on that. Maybe it is, if one is unsure if right, then it's wrong.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: It's always been a bit of a tricky one, but I _think_ this is as close to consensus as we're ever going to get. ref: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/281387/560648

Comment: @sweetsm: Currently you have chosen to fight two problems head on: implementing a linked list, and implementing strings. Choose one. E.g. use `std::string` for the strings, and do the list. Or use `std::list` for the list and do the strings. Assuming this is all for purposes of learning.

Comment: I don't want to use either of std list or string, that's the whole problem

Answer (score 0):

I spotted two things which seem wrong.

a) This line

```
list * tmp = (struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
```

is wrong (used in two functions). You need a pointer - not a new element - so no need for `malloc`.

b) This code

```
    if (tmp->next == NULL){
        tmp->next = neww;
        break;
    }
```

seems to get active when you reach the last element. However, you must still check if the new element is to be inserted before or after the element already in the list. Your code always place the new element after. Consider the case when your list only have 1 element.

BTW - If you want to write c++ you should use `std::string` instead of c-style char arrays. Also, take a look at `std::multimap` instead of your own linked list.